# Renewing iOS Developer Program with Lebanese credit card

Tags: hardware-recommendation, billing

Since I emailed apple three times now and shockingly got no response at all, I am laying out my problem here.

I am trying to renew my developer program using a lebanese credit card that has a lebanese billing address. However Apple is obliging me to pay through the US store using a US credit card (US billing address!)

What am I supposed to do??

Answer (score 1):

I had a case where i needed to add a credit card to the Hong Kong App Store, but i only had a Thai credit card. I called them and they said that i should just use the Thai credit card and the Thai address, even though the country was fixed to Hong Kong. I tried it and it worked. Have you tried this?